# How do you test javascript methods only visible in the closure scope?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, closures, jasmine

Say I have the following javascript:

```
function Foo() {

    function privateStuff() {
       //do private stuff
    }

    this.publicStuff = function() {
        privateStuff();
        //do other stuff
    }

}
```

It's easy enough to test `publicStuff()` by doing the following:

```
var myFoo = new Foo();
myFoo.publicStuff();
//all the assertions
```

However, I want to be able to test the `privateStuff()` method as its own unit. I'm not sure how I could go about calling it on it's own. I know with Java (with which I am much more familiar) you can use reflection to test private methods, but I'm wondering if there's any way to test these functions on their own. If there's no general way of doing this, I've started playing around with [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) to run my unit tests. Does this framework provide any capability for this?

Comment: Perhaps you should do black box testing on Foo instead of white box testing, where you know the implementation. Or expose the implementation in a way that makes white box testing possible.

Comment: I've heard this argument before, but I want to make sure these helper/util non-exposed functions are doing their unit of work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have your code up there, you can't. You don't allow anything to have scoped access to `privateStuff`. It seems to me that you need to read up on the concept of closures (which is fundamental to JavaScript).

Whenever you use a `f() { ... }` construct in JS (and several others, like `try-catch` blocks), you always implicitly create a closure. Nesting functions as you did is perfectly legal, but unless you give the external function an external reference to the internal function, the internal function can only be accessed from within the external function.

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope):

> You can nest a function within a function. The nested (inner) function is private to its  containing (outer) function. It also forms a closure.
>
> A closure is an expression (typically a function) that can have free
>   variables together with an environment that binds those variables
>   (that "closes" the expression).
>
> Since a nested function is a closure, this means that a nested
>   function can "inherit" the arguments and variables of its containing
>   function. In other words, the inner function contains the scope of the
>   outer function.
>
> - The inner function can be accessed only from statements in the outer    function.
> - The inner function forms a closure: the inner function can use the    arguments and

Even though the Mozilla documentation perpetuates this, it's slightly incorrect to say stuff is `private` or `public` in Javascript as the nomenclature has very well-defined meaning in most programming languages (like C++ and Java) that relates to polymorphic behavior or inheritance. As far as JS is concerned, it's better to think of it as scope-limited and try to gain a strong understanding of closures.

Comment: Er, no. A block is not a scope in JavaScript; a function is the only thing that creates a scope. (Re: part about the `{ ... }` construct)

Comment: @minitech - try-catch blocks also introduce a new scope, but you are otherwise correct.

Comment: Yes they do. The behavior has been documented and observed many a time: http://augustli.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/javascript-pitfalls-no-block-scope/ & http://danbeam.org/blog/2011/05/23/turns-out-there-is-block-scope-in-javascript-kinda/ (too lazy to look up the ECMA paragraph but it's there also!).

Comment: That's only a new scope for the one caught variable, not an actual new scope, but... okay :)

Comment: `with () { ... }` also slightly modifies the **lexical** scope, but that's a somewhat special case. Before your edited from your previous comment, you seemed to have misunderstood how scope is changed in `try-catch` blocks. Here's a (possibly useful) example: http://jsfiddle.net/CUbwA/17/ taken from one of the aforementioned sources.

Comment: No, I just misread the code example there. Anyway - `catch` creates a new scope for one variable. Nothing except a function in JavaScript creates an actual new scope for variables declared within it.

Comment: Of course, the new variable can be an object.. or a function itself, allowing you to declare members that are functionally equivalent to what you describe! :D

Comment: ... one at a time, which is even less useful than using a function, but... okay :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15702/discussion-between-david-titarenco-and-minitech)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it from outside, that's why it's "private". You could expose it temporarily:

```
this.privateStuff = privateStuff;
```

Or do the testing from inside the scope, if that's possible with however you're testing it...

Comment: Well, I was initially wondering if there was some general way of accomplishing this, but it sounds like there isn't. I've started playing around with Jasmine to do some javascript unit testing.